# Is it bad practise to restore at already restored but older MySQL databases?

Tags: mysql, linux, restore

I have an situation when I've restored databases( with flag --all-databases) 2 weeks ago, but now I need newer data in few DB, so my question is can I just mysqldump < newbackup with already installed databases or I need to remove all data? Please provide me simplest or fastest way to restore new instance.
In sqldump I have sentences like  `CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/`

Answer (score 1):

By default, your dump file will include `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements, so any tables that exist and the data in them will be dropped first. Then the tables as they exist in your dump will be restored.

Note this might even mean that the tables themselves might not have the same columns and indexes. They'll be recreated as they are defined in your dump file. Any alterations made since the dump was created will be lost when the table is dropped.

Any tables that exist in your current database that aren't in the dump file won't be touched. That is, if you created another table since your dump file was created, then there's no DROP & CREATE in the dump file. So restoring the dump won't do anything to the newer tables. This might lead to some inconsistencies, if the newer tables reference data in the restored tables.

It's possible that the `DROP TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE` statements will be missing from the dump file. There are options for `mysqldump` that make the dump omit these statements (refer to documentation or `mysqldump --help`). But by default, these statements are present.